# share text with Facebook messenger

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to share a text in Facebook messenger, like I do with WhatsApp, with this code:

`String(format: "whatsapp://send?text=%@", textToShare!))`

is there something similar with fb-messenger:// where I can choose a user from a list and send it a text?

thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios

Answer (score 3):

I think URL scheme for Messenger is what you are looking for:

```
fb-messenger://share/?link= https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fsharing%2Freference%2Fsend-dialog&app_id=123456789
```

This will open up Messenger and let you choose the users to send to.

[image]

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/web

Comment: Bing, when I do this from my iOS app it does not come in like you show above.  Above where it says "vulcanpost.com mine says "nativethirdparty".  Also, where your example shows "Getting everyone..." mine shows nothing.  Any ideas?  I have been struggling with this for days and noone seems to be able to shed any light on my issue.

Comment: The "Getting everyone..." is the meta description for the link that you are sharing. Just make sure that you have "<meta property="og:description" content="Some-description-goes-here." />" set. Remember to debug your link at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, and make sure the meta are refreshed correctly.

Comment: @BingHan I am trying to share both text and url to Facebook Messenger. But I am not able to achieve. Can you please share step by step implementation. I have integrated Facebook SDK in my app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The URL scheme is `fb-messenger://user-thread/{user-id}`. Just build your app with `fb-messenger` URL scheme as Viewer and trapped the URL on the `UIApplication` delegate. The `user-id` parameter is long integer one, as in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

[image]

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the recipient user, I would like to have a friends picker, like in whatspp!

Comment: you need to authenticate fb then you can fetch the contacts from it and share.

Comment: but I'm authenticated, I have only a friends that has may app installed! I don't have all friends!

Comment: check oiut this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

Comment: _“I have only a friends that has may app installed! I don't have all friends!”_ – works as designed; that is all your app is _supposed_ to have access to.

Comment: but I'm authenticated, I have only a friends that has may app installed! I don't have all friends! -----> yes, i have same problem. can you help me to.